# Error: Unexpected request: DELETE /rez/remove/resume/mockFile1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am new to angular and I am writing unit test for the services. So I have a delete request so, I was facing some `Error: Unexpected request: DELETE /rez/remove/resume/mockFile1`
,

```
it('should give the message after deleting the file', function() {
           var fileName1 = "mockFile1";
           var documentType = "resume";
           httpBackend.expect('DELETE', 'rez/remove/resume/mockFile1').respond(
               "File is removed"
           );

           uploadService.deleteFile(fileName1, documentType)
                .then(function(response) {
                    expect(response).tobe('File is removed');
                });
       });
```

So, Here When I call the request the response is a string which is  `"File is removed"`
 But here I am facing that error. Can any one please tell me the problem here  ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the unexpected request to?

Comment: Error: Unexpected request: DELETE /rez/remove/resume/mockFile1

Comment: Try putting a slash in front of the path in the expect?